# In Matlab how to use variables for the numbers in scientific notation (matissa and exponent)?

Tags: matlab, exponent, mantissa

I am using **Matlab** and using numbers in [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), which are represented with the letter `e` for the exponent. An example in Matlab:

```
>> 2e5
ans =
200000
```

Now would like to work with numbers in scientific notation, but using variables to hold the values of the *mantissa* and the *exponent* (left and right side of the `e` respectively). I do not understand how this can be done without the variable names merging with the letter `e` for the exponent. Eg:

```
>> rr=5;
>> 2err
??? 2err
|
Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator.
```

Can this still be done? Or must I use the manual approach:

```
>> 2*10^rr
ans =
200000
```

Comment: `2*10^rr` is the answer.  There is no `e` operator like you are looking for.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you're doing this in the first place. If it's so you can maintain precision over a larger range of numbers, there's decimal data types or extended-precision/arbitrary-precision math for that. Don't reinvent the wheel!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the manual approach; you can't use scientific notation like that with variables. You might want to use `2.*10.^rr`, with the `.`, to enable you to use the same statement with arrays of numbers.